# How to change visibility of div's child elements in "onmouseover" function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

In my website I would like to change some style properties of a div when user moves the mouse over it. I would also like to hide/show some child elements of this div. I don't have any experience with JavaScript, I'm experimenting with some code I found in the Internet.

Let's say my div looks like that:

```
<div class="Advertisement">
    <h2 class="Title">title</h2>
</div>
```

And I want to hide this h2 element after moving the mouse over the div. My JS Script looks like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var lis = document.getElementsByClassName("Advertisement");
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].onmouseover = function() {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            this.style.width = "800px";
            var children = lis[i].childNodes.getElementsByClassName("Title");
            for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
                children[j].onmouseover = function() {
                    this.style.visibility = "hidden";
                };
            }
        };
    }
};​
```

Changing of size and background color works fine, but the "h2" element doesn't disappear. What did I do wrong?

Comment: did you try .style.display="hidden"?

Comment: Do you want the colour to change, the width to change and the element to disappear all at the same time, because currently you are only adding another 'onmouseover' event to the <h2> when the background colour and width are changed.

Comment: @PsyCoder - I tried, but it didn't help.

Comment: are you willing to use jquery?

Comment: @phenomnomnominal - damn, you're right :P I changed it to children[j].style.visibility = "hidden" , but doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need JavaScript for that task. Why not use plain HTML/CSS?

Try this:

```
<style>
    div.advertisement:hover > h2, div.advertisement:focus > h2 {
        color:      red;
    }
    div.advertisement > h3 {
        display:    none;
    }
    div.advertisement:hover > h3, div.advertisement:focus > h3 {
        display:    block;
    }
</style>

<div class="advertisement" tabindex="-1">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <h3>hidden text</h3>
</div>
```

This one actually shows something, but of course it works vice versa with hiding your h2.

---

*Extension by RyanB*

This is similiar to an answer I'd give. I would say the hidden text should be a `<p>, <span> or a <div>` versus a `<h3>` to have better semantics. Also add `tabindex="-1"` to the div if it is that important. Adding `tabindex="-1"` allows the `<div>` to receive focus.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Thanks @ryan for this extension, as it adds the click coming from ":focus". Your are right about the headlines, but this was just an example how it could be done - without worrying much about the semantics used in the container. :)

Comment: Thanks for approving the edit. The :focus pseudo-class actually is triggered when you tab to an element. Adding tabindex -1, allows non-focusable elements (stuff other than links and form elements) to get focus.

Answer (score 0):

lis[i] is undefined here and no need of childnode
So,instead of this

```
var children = lis[i].childNodes.getElementsByClassName("Title");
```

Write

```
 var children = this.getElementsByClassName("Title");
```